# Laravel 8: Function params must be an array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have a route that must get some parameters:

`Route::get('users/{function}/{param}/{feeLimit}/{callValue}/{bandwidthLimit}' , [TronController::class, 'totalUsers']);`

And the method `totalUsers` looks like this:

`public function totalUsers($function,$params,$feeLimit,$callValue,$bandwidthLimit){`

And in the browser, I call it like this:

`http://localhost:8000/users/totalUsers/array()/30000000/0/0`

But now I get this error:

`Function params must be an array`

I know this way of adding parameters is wrong, but I don't how to call the url and variables like this on the browser:

```
$function="totalUsers";
$params=array();
$feeLimit=30000000;
$callValue = 0;
$bandwidthLimit = 0;
```

How can I call `totalUsers` method properly with its parameters?

### Update 1

In the method `totalUsers`:

```
try {
            $trigger = $TransactionBuilder->triggerSmartContract(
                (array)$abi,
                $contractH,
                $function,
                $params,
                $feeLimit,
                $addressH,
                $callValue = 0,
                $bandwidthLimit = 0);
            var_dump($trigger);
        } catch (\IEXBase\TronAPI\Exception\TronException $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: What do you want to pass as `params`?

Comment: @BABAKASHRAFI I just added an **UPDATE 1**

Comment: @BABAKASHRAFI But at another method (`totalTickets`) I need to add `$params=array("0"=>$i);`

Comment: Your question is unclear. But I think using *query string* may help you do your job. You can retrieve any query string in laravel using `request()->get('params')`.

Comment: @BABAKASHRAFI I need a unique method parameter and route parameter for adding any custom data

Comment: You will need to serialize the array if you want to send it as route parameter.

Comment: @VishnuR PLEASE tell me how, my career depends on this

Comment: ``http://localhost:8000/users/totalUsers/a:0:{}/30000000/0/0`` try this 
It wont be a pretty.

Comment: @VishnuR Again `Function params must be an array` :(

Comment: ``route('totalUsers', $room->id, serialize($array))`` use the route helper function, where totalUsers is the name of the route and add other parameters as per requirement

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232804/discussion-between-vishnu-r-and-kkk-kkk).

Answer (score 1):

Easily You can solve this problem by using this route as post:

```
Route::post('/users' , [TronController::class, 'totalUsers'])->name('users');
```

Then you can send the value by submitting a form:

```
<form action="{{ route('users') }}" method="post">
@csrf
<input type="text" name="function" />
<input type="text" name="params[]" />
<input type="text" name="params[]" />
<input type="text" name="params[]" />
.... // how much you want
<input type="text" name="feeLimit" />
<input type="text" name="callValue" />
<input type="text" name="bandwidthLimit" />
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

You will be getting an array for this params field, this is secure and you can send a large number of data character:
In the controller:

```
public function totalUsers(Request $request)
{
  $function=$request->function;
  $params=$request->param; // this will be an array
  $feeLimit=$request->feeLimit;
  $callValue = $request->callValue;
  $bandwidthLimit = $request->bandwidthLimit;
  foreach( $params as $param )
  {
       $param; // do what ever you want
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error has nothing to do with routes, it's a [`tron-api`'s error](https://github.com/iexbase/tron-api/blob/master/src/TransactionBuilder.php#L474-L475). The `triggerSmartContract()` function expects `$params` to be an array, but you're passing a string.

Easy way to solve that would be just convert your `$params` string to array in the arguments `(array)$params`.

Correct way would be to follow advice in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67670335/534943), though I'd suggest to validate user input:

```php
public function totalUsers(Request $request)
{
  $request->validate([
    'function'       => 'required|string',
    'params'         => 'required|array',
    'feeLimit'       => 'required|numeric',
    'callValue'      => 'sometimes|numeric',
    'bandwidthLimit' => 'sometimes|numeric',
  ]);

  try {
    $trigger = $TransactionBuilder->triggerSmartContract(
      (array)$abi,
      $contractH,
      $request->input('function'),
      $request->input('params'),
      $request->input('feeLimit'),
      $addressH,
      $request->input('callValue', 0),
      $request->input('bandwidthLimit', 0)
    );
    var_dump($trigger);
  } catch (\IEXBase\TronAPI\Exception\TronException $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
  }
}
```